# cakePHP complex find query

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

how do I build a find() query in cakePHP using these conditions:

```
Find where 
MyModel.x = 1 and MyModel.y = 2 OR 
MyModel.x = 1 and MyModel.y value does not exist (or is equal to empty string)
```

Can somebody tell me how I can go about building such find query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna give you some pointers, but you need to try to do this as it's very basic and it's always good to practice.

A basic find in cake is in the form of

```
$this->ModelName->find('all');
```

This in its default form does a `SELECT * from model_names` (convention is to have singular ModelName for plural table name - `model_names`)

To add conditions:

```
$this->ModelName->find('all', array('conditions' => array('ModelName.x' => 1));
```

To add AND conditions

```
$this->ModelName->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
   'ModelName.x' => 1, 'ModelName.y' => 2
));
```

To add OR conditions

```
$this->ModelName->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
   'OR' => array(
      'ModelName.x' => 1, 'ModelName.y' => 2
    )
));
```

To combine both

```
$this->ModelName->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
   'ModelName.y is not' => null,
   'OR' => array(
      'ModelName.x' => 1, 'ModelName.y' => 2
    )
));

// where y is not null and (x = 1 or y = 2)
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

(btw I'm sure there will be users giving you the exact answers, so just take my answer for your reference :) )

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->MyModel->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
    'OR' => array(
         array(
             'MyModel.x' => 1,
             'MyModel.y' => 1
         ),
         array(
             'MyModle.x' => 1,
             'OR' => array(
                  array('MyModel.y' => NULL),
                  array('MyModel.y' => '')
             )
         )
    )
)));
```